# Last Action Event get Fired on back Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Form which contains :
Category TextBox
Button to Save the TextBox value in database.

The code works fine, all textbox value get Saved successfully on Save Button Click.

Problem:
After Saving I redirect to same page, and now here when I click on some link suppose 'Google.Com' and then if I click back button the browser redirect me to previous page on my application. **on Click on Back Button** the Postback value is found to be True, and again Save Button Event gets Fired **and again textbox value gets saved in database.**

I don't want the event must get fired on back click.
What should I do?

Please help me , I m getting issue and not getting solution on it.

Comment: try http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/defeat-the-evil-back-button-in-your-asp-net-applications/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to implement a Post/Redirect/Get ([PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)) pattern in your app.  The basic rule is that your POST should not return a page (or a view); instead, it should return just a redirect request that will GET the page/view to show.

While you'll find a lot more information about PRG in relation to ASP.NET MVC, I'm assuming your working with web forms - so there's not much in terms of examples out there that I'm familiar with.

But the concept is pretty straight-forward.  After your POST, just return a Response.Redirect back to the page that you want to display.  It may seem like duplicate work, but you'll save yourself the problems that you're describing.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, problem got solved with your solution. But I want to show that data is saved in msg div tag on same page after saving data, this would not be possible after redirecting.

Comment: Anything's possible!  :)  You have a few options.  You could redirect and have a parameter on the URL that ties to the ID of the item that you saved in the database, so that your GET will query the database for the data just saved, retrieve it, and populate the page.  Or, and this depends on how much data is involved and how sensitive it is, but you could create a cookie that contains the data in the POST, issue the redirect, and then retrieve the data from the cookie in your GET. You'd also want to expire the cookie in the GET.  Probably a few other options, too.

Comment: Ya you are right, the above options will work, but unhappy with this method. Anywayz, thanks for you support. My problem got solved with your suggestion.